# how to give elements of $A × B$ and $A ∩ B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

$A$ = {$3n+1: n∈Z$} and $B$ = {$12m+7: m∈Z$}

I have proven that $A⊄B$ by showing that $3n+1$ $⇒$ $3n+1+7-7$ ⇒ $3n-6+7$ ⇒ $3(n-2)+7$ ⇒ $4((3(n-2))+7)/4$ ⇒ $12(n-2)(1/4) +7$ ⇒ $12m-7$, where $m = (n-2)(1/4)$, and this proves that $A⊄B$, since $m$ will not always give an integer value.

I have also proved that $B⊆A$ by showing that $12m+7$ ⇒ $12m+7-6+6$ ⇒ $12m+6+1$ ⇒ $3(4m+2)+1$ ⇒ $3n+1$, where $n = (4m+2)$.

If my proofs for the above statements can be improved, let me know.

Now, I am trying to work on giving two concrete elements of $A × B$ and giving two concrete elements of $A ∩ B$.

$A × B$ is defined as $:=$ {$(a,b): a∈A$ and $b∈B$}

$A ∩ B$ is defined as $=$ {$x: (x∈A)$ and $(x∈B)$}

I am not exactly sure how to give concrete elements on $A × B$ and $A ∩ B$ or what it means to give concrete elements. If someone can explain this to me, I would really appreciate it.

Could I say that a concrete element of $A×B$ is $(1,6)$ and $(3, 10)$? I say that $b=6$ and $b=10$ because $(n−2)(1/4)$ will give an integer with those values of $b$? I am not sure what makes an element "concrete" and if I am understanding this correctly.

Could I say that a concrete element of $A∩B$ is $x=10$ or $x=6$ or $x=0$ or $x=14$. I am basically giving out numbers that $(n−2)(1/4)$ will yield an integer value for, since $B$ is contained in $A$, so all values of $B$ will work for $A$ but not the other way around?

Thanks for any answers given!

Comment: I haven't looked through it, but your proof that $A \subseteq B$ can't be true, as $4 \in A$ but $4 \notin B$.

Comment: @DuncanRamage why can't $4∈B$? Can you explain this to me, I have just started working with sets.

Comment: The simplest proof that $A \not\subset B$ is to write down a counterexample of the defining statement "if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$". So we write down $x=1$ and then we prove that $x \in A$ and $x \not\in B$.

Comment: @charles Loosely speaking: the function $f(m) = 12m + 7$ is an increasing function, that is if I put in bigger $m$ I get a bigger output. $f(-1) = -5 < 7 = f(0)$, so this function "skips over" 4.

Comment: Another way of seeing this is $A$ is the set of all numbers which have a remainder of 1 when divided by 3 while $B$ is all those numbers with a remainder of 7 when divided by 12. The remainder of 4 divided by 3 is 1, the remainder of 4 divided by 12 is 4.

Answer (score 1):

$A\times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs or couples $(x,y)$ satisfying these 2 conditons :

(1) x belongs to $A$

(2) y belongs to $B$.

So , simply find an $x$ that meets the conditions to belong to $A$ and a $y$ that meets the conditions to belong to $B$, and "build" an ordered pair ( properly ordered of course!) with them; this ordered pair will automatcally be an element of $A\times B$.

In order to find  a member of $A\cap B$, just find an object (here , a number) that meets both the conditions to belong to $A$ and to belong to $B$ .

It could happen that no number meets these 2 conditions. In that case $ A\cap B$ would be identical to $\emptyset$ ( the empty set).

Now, in order to know whether it is the case, you could suppose you have found a number X that belongs to both sets.

You'd have $X = 3n+1$ and $X = 12m+7$.

This implies : $3n+1 = 12m+7$.

Some algebraic  manipulations will give you a certain relation between $n$ and $m$ that must occur in order $X$ to belong both to $A$ and to $B$.

Note : this relation must be compatible with the fact that $n$ and $m$ are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a concrete element of $A \times B$ amounts to finding a concrete element $a$ of $A$, and a concrete element $b$ of $B$, and then writing $(a, b)$.

Similarly, giving a concrete element of $A \cap B$ amounts to finding a concrete element $a$ of $A$ which also happens to be an element of $B$.

Also, you are unfortunately mistaken that $A \subseteq B$. We have $1 \in A$ but $1 \notin B$. Perhaps you were trying to prove the other direction?

Comment: Sorry can you explain to me why $1∉B$? Someone else commented that $A⊆B$ is wrong, because  $4∉B$, but I don't completely understand why it can't work?

Comment: @charles: Because $(n-2)\left(\dfrac14\right)$ isn't always an integer. Think about it!

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Right! I completely forgot about that part! Thanks so much!!

Comment: So, could I say that a concrete element of $A×B$ is (1,6) and (3, 10)? I say that $b=6$ and $b=10$ because $(n−2)(1/4)$ will give an integer with those values of $b$? I am not sure what makes an element "concrete" and if I am understanding this correctly.